# Android Warning message: Attempt to retrieve bag which is invalid or in a cycle

Tags: android

I see  warning message in LogCat saying:

ResourceType: Attempt to retrieve bag 0x7f080015 which is invalid or in a cycle.

The warning message repeats 50+ times which is really annoying. What does it mean? And how do I make it go away?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that the project has a style defined under "values-fr" but no counterpart under the default values folder.

Comment: That's great but... how did you discover that? And how could anyone (i.e. me :-) ) find out which one's the offending style?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I was getting that message because I was using the following method to override my styles for different API levels:

```
<style name="ToolBar" parent="ToolBar.Base"/>

<style name="ToolBar.Base">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">?actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

And then adding

```
<style name="ToolBar" parent="ToolBar.Base">
    <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
</style>
```

in my v21/styles file. It's the period between ToolBar and Base that's causing the problem. Replace that with an underscore or a different name with no period and you should be fine. For more on why, read what Android has to say about [Style and Theme Inheritance](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Inheritance).

Anyway, I changed `ToolBar.Base` to `ToolBar_Base`, and no more error messages.